# How to calculate the time spent at location for each unique ID per day?

Tags: r, time-series

I'm currently working on the smartGPA dataset (https://studentlife.cs.dartmouth.edu/smartgpa.pdf) and I was trying to calculate the time spend studying at a location at each day for each student (UID) to eventually get a mean study time for each student. I have timestamp data and location data for each student based on wifi location data. For example, in the data you can see that a student spends time at the library from 6:55:54 until 7:05:34, then I want to subtract those times to get the time spend studying.

I created an extra column which subtracts row x+1 - row x = time difference between 2 rows. If the difference between those rows is larger than 15 minutes, then I need to stop summing up the time difference and start over again for a new study instance. Is there a simple way to do this? For example, I would sum up timediff from row 1 till 8, and discard rows 9, 10, 11 since their time difference is larger than 15 minutes.

[image]

```
structure(list(timestamp = c(1364385354L, 1364385374L, 1364385384L, 
1364385454L, 1364385763L, 1364385856L, 1364385868L, 1364385934L, 
1364392663L, 1364392681L, 1364397495L, 1364397505L, 1364397923L, 
1364411988L, 1364412078L, 1364412163L, 1364412406L, 1364412453L, 
1364412968L, 1364413005L), location = c("in[baker-berry]", "in[baker-berry]", 
"in[baker-berry]", "in[baker-berry]", "in[baker-berry]", "in[baker-berry]", 
"in[baker-berry]", "in[baker-berry]", "in[dana-library]", "in[dana-library]", 
"in[dana-library]", "in[dana-library]", "in[baker-berry]", "in[baker-berry]", 
"in[baker-berry]", "in[baker-berry]", "in[baker-berry]", "in[baker-berry]", 
"in[baker-berry]", "in[baker-berry]"), uid = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
"19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", 
"30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", 
"41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", 
"52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59"), class = "factor"), 
    hour = c(12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 
    16L, 16L, 16L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), epoch = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("nig", "mor", "aft", "eve"), class = "factor"), 
    day = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3), week = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), weekday = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L), .Label = c("mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", 
    "sun"), class = "factor"), time = structure(c(1364385354, 
    1364385374, 1364385384, 1364385454, 1364385763, 1364385856, 
    1364385868, 1364385934, 1364392663, 1364392681, 1364397495, 
    1364397505, 1364397923, 1364411988, 1364412078, 1364412163, 
    1364412406, 1364412453, 1364412968, 1364413005), tzone = "EST", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("timestamp_SL_tbl", 
"SL_tbl", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), schema = "sensing", table = "wifi_location")
```

Comment: How can you tell what the groupings are supposed to be? As an example: in the [dana-library] entries, there are four consecutive entries, but the middle two are separated by an hour's gap. Does this mean there were two quick visits to the dana library, or was it one long visit that for whatever reason had no wifi ping in the middle?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery Yes, I'm not entirely sure how to achieve this either, but this is an assignment for university in which we have to predict the cumulative gpa for each student with a deep learning model. One of the variables that we should use is mean study duration. I would say that the large gap means that a student left the library and came back at a later time. I have no clue how to get process this effectively as to get the mean daily study duration...

Comment: if the student left the library and went to a different one, is that considered as two unique studying "episodes"?

Comment: Hmm -- well, your first step would seem to be establishing some conceptual rules for how to answer the groupings question, and you won't be able to proceed until you've done that. Note that the first visit to baker-berry had a 5 minute gap -- so you're implicitly saying that's OK, but that an hour's gap is not. That's perfectly reasonable, but these are the kinds of choices you'll have to make (and presumably defend later). I'll also note that in a real world sense, library visits is a bad proxy for study time since so much studying happens elsewhere, but that's perhaps neither here nor there.

Comment: @EJJ Yes I would say that those are separate study instances. I think if there is a large gap, then we shouldn't simply subtract the row from the previous row, but take that as a separate new instance.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery I agree, this is a very simplified method. In the article they also use some other sensor data to determine if a person is studying but that is out of the scope of this assignment. Do you have any experience on how to create conceptual rules for groupings? I was thinking about something like that, but don't know how to implement that. For example, if there is a gap of over 30 minutes between 2 observations I would want to classify that as 2 distinct study times and calculate study time in period 1 by taking last row - first row = total study time for study instance 1.

Comment: By "conceptual rules for groupings," I don't mean any code at all; I mean deciding, from a conceptual standpoint, what should count as a visit. The 30-minute cutoff you suggested is a good start -- but note that this approach is still incomplete; consider observation 13, which is an "island" of a baker-berry visit. Does that count as anything? If so, how long? You'll need to firmly decide this at a conceptual level before you'll be able to implement anything in code, is my point.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery i see now. I understand the conceptual rules but even after having good conceptual rules, I would have no clue how to implement something like that in code.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but you haven't laid out those conceptual rules for us yet, and until you do (by editing your question) there will be no way for anyone to help you regardless of their coding skill

Comment: can you provide the desired output from the data you've shared?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery I edited my post. Does this make it clearer?

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with the **dplyr package** and the **as.POSIXct()** function. So, first, download and then load the dplyr package if you don't yet have it.

```
install.packages("dplyr") 
library(dplyr)
```

Then, you'll want to create a new column with this time difference.
Also, preferably, you don't want to change your original data.

This could be done like this:

```
data.frame <- data.frame %>%
> mutate(time_difference = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(time1)) - as.numeric(as.POSIXct(time2)))
```

The as.numeric() function converts it in seconds, and this creates a new column with the difference also in seconds.

Now, if you want this difference in minutes, you'll only need to divide the result by 60 (there is 60 seconds in a minute). If you want it in hours, you'll only need to divide the result by 360 (there is 360 seconds in an hour).

**Let's say you want this difference by minutes.**

By then, you can either create a new column

```
data.frame <- data.frame %>%
> mutate(time_difference_seconds = time_difference /60)
```

or you could ugly it up by adding the division to the original column.

```
data.frame <- data.frame %>%
> mutate(time_difference = (as.numeric(as.POSIXct(time1)) - as.numeric(as.POSIXct(time2)))) / 60
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It did help me a bit as I now have the time difference between two rows. I edited my post to make it clearer as to what my goal exactly is

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by taking the time difference between 2 consecutive rows as noted in the description of the question and then removing all those observations with minutes longer than 15. Then I summed per student and got the total study time for each student.